# How to read file until certain character or EOF?

Tags: c, file, char, fgetc

I have small problem with my C code. I want to read file until I hit certain character or EOF (from parameter as seen now). `char *readUntil(FILE *stream, char character, size_t *length)`

I used this loop:`int i = 0` `while((i = fgetc(stream)) != character || i != EOF){}` to read it until stream ends or character is matched. However it doesnt seem to be working. What's the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `while((i = fgetc(stream)) != character && i != EOF){}` NOTE the `&&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
while((i = fgetc(stream)) != character || i != EOF){}
```

will loop forever as either

```
i = fgetc(stream)) != character
```

or

```
i != EOF
```

will be true.

Try

```
while((i = fgetc(stream)) != character && i != EOF){}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now that i is number and not character, how can I convert it to char so I could store it to array?

Comment: @JonH In C, `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are actually integer types.